# Close menu on click outside

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, navbar

I have seen many questions about this in here and all over the internet and I still can´t get a solution that works for me. This is the code of my menu, made with bootstrap. It works fine when you click on it in small screens, however, I can´t close it unless I click the close sign. I would like to close it when I click on one of the links or in at least when I click outside the menu in the page.

```
  <header id="main-nav">
<div class="container">
  <a  id="navigation" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
  <div id="slide_out_menu" >
    <a href="#" class="menu-close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
    <div class="logo"><img src="images/asesoria-arturo-soria.png" alt="Asesoría Arturo Soria Logo" title="Asesoría Arturo Soria"></div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#servicios" class="smoothScroll">Servicios</a></li>
      <li><a href="#autonomos" class="smoothScroll">Autónomos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#empresas" class="smoothScroll">Empresas</a></li>
      <li><a href="#startups" class="smoothScroll">Startups</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contacta" class="smoothScroll">Contacta</a></li>
      <li><a class="sociales" href="https://www.facebook.com/Asesoria-Arturo-Soria-120615058061098/?fref=ts" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
      <a class="sociales" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/asesoria-arturo-soria-a0130143" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    <div class="slide_out_menu_footer">
      <div class="more-info">
        <p>Creado y diseñado por <a href="http://hdeprada.com/">Hdeprada.com</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul class="left">
    <li><a href="#autonomos" class="smoothScroll">Autónomos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#empresas" class="smoothScroll">Empresas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#startups" class="smoothScroll">Startups</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
      <a href="#header" class="logo smoothScroll"><img src="images/asesoria-arturo-soria.png" alt="Asesoría Arturo Soria Logo" title="Asesoría Arturo Soria"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <ul class="right">
        <li><a href="#servicios" class="smoothScroll">Servicios</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contacta" class="smoothScroll">Contacta</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Asesoria-Arturo-Soria-120615058061098/?fref=ts" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/asesoria-arturo-soria-a0130143" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying this code for example and it does not work:

```
$('html').click(function() {
    $('#slide_out_menu').hide();
});

$('#slide_out_menu').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

The following code is working in my main.js file. It works on the click in .menu-close but if I change it for body or html it does not work. Why is this?

```
    $('#navigation').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('open');
        $('#slide_out_menu').toggleClass('open');

        if ($('#slide_out_menu').hasClass('open')) {
            $('.menu-close').on('click', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#slide_out_menu').removeClass('open');
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following:

```
$("body").on("click", function(e) {
   $(".collapse").collapse("hide");
});
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

Also found this: http://www.bootply.com/63158

Comment: With that it does not let me open the menu. So I don´t know if it would close it.

Comment: I just posted an update.  Is that what your looking for?